# How close to platonic can a non-platonic planar graph be?

Tags: graph-theory

Direct question:

Is it possible to construct a finite, planar, $k$-regular graph in which all the faces except one have the same degree (are bounded by a cycle with the same number of edges), and the remaining face (the external face, if you like) has a distinct degree?  If not, why not?  If so, what is an example of such a graph?

Context:

I'm teaching a course in combinatorics this fall and, as the University describes graph theory being part of the curriculum, I brushed up on some and incorporated a fellow prof's notes on basic graph theory for part of the semester.  The Platonic solids are a nice basic example, so we did that proof.

So, in defining a platonic graph, one says that such a graph is planar and regular, and all faces have the same degree.  I thought that a student might misclassify a graph as platonic if the external face had a different degree, and set about trying to draw such an example.  This proving difficult, I started thinking that it can't be done.  I invited the students to prove it as a project, and moved on.  My attempts to produce such a graph systematically showed me how to do it with an infinite graph -- take a pentagon and extend squares off to infinity, e.g. -- or with two faces of different, equal degree -- a prism on any polygon.  And these suggest a route of proof, but I'm not steeped in enough graph theory at the moment to come up with it.  The previous prof couldn't work out a proof on short notice either.  This isn't unexpectedly hard, is it?  I'd like to be able to give my students a conclusion on this before we end the unit.

Comment: You get quite a bit of constraints from Euler formula $v-e+f=2$: your graph is regular, i.e. $2e=vk$, and the $f-1$ faces are $\ell$-gonal, while the remaining face is $\ell'$-gonal. So this gives $2e=(f-1)\ell+\ell'$. Finally, don't forget topology, which forbids $\ell$ greater than 5...

Comment: Yes, there is a 1-dimensional family of numerical solutions for $(k,\ell)=(3,3),(3,4),(3,5),(4,3),(5,3)$ and that's all. They can considered separately for whether they are realizable as graphs.

Comment: The case $(3,3)$ doesn't work since $\ell'<e$.